# In QGIS processing modeller, how to use an input number in an expression?

Tags: qgis-processing

I'm making a model where I need to use a certain years in a bunch of expressions. For example:

```
""era_2" > YEAR1"
"era_2" > YEAR2 AND "era_2" < YEAR1
"era_2" >= YEAR3 AND "ERA_2" <= YEAR1
```

It's confusing at the moment for other people using the model. So is there a way I can use an input number in the expression?

Comment: Different feature storage types see dates differently, what sort of data is this? A shapefile, KML, geodatabase etc? I take it that era_2 is a datetime field or is it a string?

Comment: Are you hoping to replace the field name (`"era_2"`) in your expression, or the year number variables (`YEAR1`, `YEAR2`, `YEAR3`)?

Answer (score 1):

You should have number parameter listed in expression dialog.

In this model I have `num` parameter for taking number from user, entered value is then used as Z value.

Its posible to use parameter by entering `@num` or `paramater('num')`

[image]